# Resize firefox window under 400 px

Tags: windows, firefox, window-resize

I don´t know what happend in Firefox, i don´t know if it´s a problem with this brownser or what, but actually i test responsive website and always i can resize window under 400px and more, and test for 250px the width, etc.

I see some solutions but for me not good, also i test firefox developer and result it´s the same, i can´t resize window under 400px, when always i can do this, really it´s ridiculous.

My question it´s some people here have this situation and know how put the size of firefox under 400 px, because i think it´s very easy for everybody test responsive website simple resize window and no more.

This it´s my question how i can resize firefox window under 400px as i can do time ago, and now impossible, i understand Firefox put minimun width resize to 400px but how i can change this.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

**For people wants solution for this :**

Create in user profile of firefox css file :

> /* Reduce minimum window width for Fx74 */
> :root:not([chromehidden~="toolbar"]){   /* Fx74 default is 450px on
> Windows */   min-width: 250px !important; }

Save as userChrome.css

Until create in user firefox folder other folder called chrome

Open firefox and go to about:config

Search userprof

Set toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets to True

Close Firefox and Reload and you can resize the window as you want and no restricted width.

Regards